# Bluelist app throws "Enroll failed to create remote cloudant database for Optional("test1"). timeout

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant, ibm-mobile-services

I have a Bluelist app based on this [bluemix sample app](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-ios-bluelist). I added some more types of data into the DB and also changed the Node.Js app, so that there is only one "todosdb" created for different users.

In the last few days it threw the following errors a few times. When I deleted the remote DB, it did run again. But it just threw the same error again. I deleted the DB, did not fix it this time. Still getting the same error. Also tried the sample app itself, it throws the same error. Can someone tell me how to debug it?

```
       2015-11-13 20:06:33.303 bluelist-swift[57121:1075334] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[IMFAuthorizationRequest requestFinished:] in IMFAuthorizationRequest.m:341 :: Response Header: {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Fri, 13 Nov 2015 20:06:33 GMT";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Backside-Transport" = "OK OK";
    "X-Cf-Requestid" = "b5bf38ed-a48b-4e69-4852-bb1f4c81011a";
    "X-Client-IP" = "80.111.218.187";
    "X-Global-Transaction-ID" = 1902424573;
    "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0";
}
Response Data: {"token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImpwayI6eyJhbGciOiJSU0EiLCJleHAiOiJBUUFCIiwibW9kIjoiQxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
Status code=200
    2015-11-13 20:06:33.320 bluelist-swift[57121:1075334] [INFO] [BlueList] Authenticated user with id test1
    2015-11-13 20:06:33.325 bluelist-swift[57121:1075334] [DEBUG] [IMF_OAUTH] -[IMFAuthorizationManager releaseCompletionHandlerQueue:error:] in IMFAuthorizationManager.m:428 :: Completion handlers queue released.
    2015-11-13 20:06:33.326 bluelist-swift[57121:1075334] [DEBUG] [IMF_OAUTH] -[IMFAuthorizationManager clearCompletionHandlerQueue] in IMFAuthorizationManager.m:437 :: Completion handler queue cleared
    2015-11-13 20:07:33.734 bluelist-swift[57121:1075334] [ERROR] [BlueList] Enroll failed to create remote cloudant database for Optional("test1").  Error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdef2e18dc0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://chatbms.mybluemix.net/bluelist/enroll, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://chatbms.mybluemix.net/bluelist/enroll, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.})
```

Comment: I see that the request to your node.js application has time out:

https://chatbms.mybluemix.net/bluelist/enroll

"The request timed out."

Can you please verify the node.js portion of your application is running and is accessible from your device. Also make sure that /enroll portion is included in your node.js application

From hitting the URL in my browser I can see it is deployed, but make sure you have a good internet connection from your device as well

Comment: Hey Zheng Xie...is there any update to this question? Did you verify that the node.js application was running?

Answer (score 1):

Bluemix was doing some maintenance, I think. It worked later.